# Widget next to another in relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have recyclerView with card views.

In cardView layout I want to have text next to heart image and share image. I want that if text is long then not be behind the heart image but it should go to the new line. Now it don't work as I want. Also my heart image is sometimes bigger than in other heart in other card views.

This is example(heart and share above is bigger than below, I want all heart and share images in the same size):
[image]

my card view layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FCFCFC"
    tools:context="showresultactivity.SlideTabsActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/someText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/someText"
                android:layout_below="@id/street"
                android:text="some"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/someText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
                android:layout_below="@id/someText2"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:text="some text "
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/street"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/cardViewLike"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
                android:text="asdasd sd sd ad ssssssowiskifd sdf"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_size_icon_next_to_text"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewLikeRed"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/street"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_red"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewLike"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/street"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="35dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_heart_white"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardViewShare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/street"
                android:background="@null"
                android:tintMode="src_over"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />





        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Sometimes it happens:

[image]

Text is under my image but it should be in a new line then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change relative rules of your **street** TextView

Try to add following:

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardViewLikeRed"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cardViewLikeRed"
```

So your TextView should look like this:

```
 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/street"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cardViewLikeRed"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagesSrcUrl"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cardViewLikeRed"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_size_icon_next_to_text"
                    android:text="asdasd sd sd ad ssdsdhjshjshkkljkljkljkljlkjkljlkjkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjljlkjlkjlkjkljlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlkjljlkjlkjdjkshjdhsdjkhjkdshfjksdhfssssowiskifd sdf"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to have a RelativeLayout as your root layout.  A RelativeLayout always has to do two measure passes, so if you place it at the root the measurement will be done twice for the whole layout/ screen.